# Yii: Cactiverecord::findall() need to retrieve from different database and return the value

Tags: php, yii

I have records in different databases. I need to return all of them when findall method is called.

I have the  getDbConnection() function in a model

```
 public function getDbConnection($db='')
 {      
    if($db!='')
    {
      $connection = Yii::app()->getComponent($db);
      return $connection;

    }

    if(self::$db!==null)
        return self::$db;
    else
    {
        self::$db=Yii::app()->getDb();

        if(self::$db instanceof CDbConnection)
            return self::$db;
        else
            throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','Active Record requires a "db" CDbConnection application component.'));
    }
  }
```

In CactiveRecord.php

```
public function getCommandBuilder($db)
{
    return $this->getDbConnection($db)->getSchema()->getCommandBuilder($db);
}


public function findAll($condition='',$params=array())
{
       Yii::trace(get_class($this).'.findAll()','system.db.ar.CActiveRecord');

  $dbconnection = array('db','dbmobisite');//db abd dbmobisite are component names in protected/config/main.php
  $returnall = array();
  foreach($dbconnection as $db)
  {     
        $criteria=$this->getCommandBuilder($db)->createCriteria($condition,$params);
        $return = $this->query($criteria,true);
        foreach($return as $values)
        {
            array_push($returnall,$values);
        }
    }

    return $returnall;
}
```

But I am getting the following error :

> Missing argument 1 for CActiveRecord::getCommandBuilder(), called in /home/jrickby/public_html/hastings.pro/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php on line 1358 and defined

and it says the error is in this function

```
public function getCommandBuilder($db)
{
    return $this->getDbConnection($db)->getSchema()->getCommandBuilder($db);
}
```

I dont know how to solve this problem, please help

Answer (score 0):

You could just create database configuration arrays in your config file and associate models with the right db config.

config/main.php

```
'components' => [
    'db' => [
        ...
    ],
    'anotherDb' => [
        ...
    ],
],
```

Override getDbConnection() in model that exists inside `anotherDb`

```
public function getDbConnection()
{
    return Yii::app()->anotherDb;
}
```